# how to create simulator for web application for load test and stress test

Tags: sql-server, testing, load, stress-testing

how can i record the web server log files and replay the the recorded server logs so that i can latter run the logs and check the load on sql server.

ex. number of request on and the number of resposes on sql server

Answer (score 3):

Build a tool that can parse the log files from the web server and replay the requests again. Then you generate test cases by accessing your site using a normal web browser and record the log files.

You can then replay the same sequence over and over again and your tool could also read multiple logs and play them back simultaneously to simulate concurrency.

Make sure that the log files include all GET and POST request parameters as well as timestamps.

Comment: can you explain it bit more i m not getting what you r trying to say...i want to rerun the same process that had take placed on web server...it is a kind of flashback for website

Comment: The web server produces log files, it you design a client that can read and parse those log files and re-send the requests. Take a look at the curl loader toolkit.

Comment: how can use curl loader toolkit to test asp.net website?

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple tools that you might find useful:

Selenium is a suite of tools specifically for testing web applications.
http://seleniumhq.org/

ab (Apache HTTP server benchmarking tool) is a tool for benchmarking your Apache Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) server. It is designed to give you an impression of how your current Apache installation performs. This especially shows you how many requests per second your Apache installation is capable of serving.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html

Comment: i dont want any tool...can you please suggest me how can i implement it...is it possible without any tool...

Comment: @girish - I don't think you understand what you're asking for.  What do you mean "without any tool"?  I gave you two pieces of technology that will help you accomplish what you're trying to do.  One lets you script web site interactions and replay them.  The other does large-scale load testing.  If this isn't helpful, then your question should be rewritten.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using a tool? Tools like selenium will exercise the front-end, you can probably setup a server and a collection of clients running on separate machines to simulate user interaction.

If you want to exercise the backend more directly you could write a unit test I suppose, but unit testing isn't really designed for doing that sort of thing.