# Performance/Load testing web application running on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, testing

Could someone recommend an open source load testing tool which allows the load/stress testing of a web application running on tomcat. I have seen Jmeter but i am struggling to get it to work properly with Javascript. 
What other popular load testing tools are out there?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[how to create simulator for web application for load test and stress test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627084/how-to-create-simulator-for-web-application-for-load-test-and-stress-test)