# how to test load of android client server application

Tags: android, web-services, performance-testing

I develop android client server application, where client are android mobiles and server is web-server.

I want to test when n number of client will access server that time what happen. I want to see if my server will run properly or it can not handle max load.

If there is any tool for android application please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **JMeter** if your Web Service runs on **Java**.

Here you have a nice SO question talking about server side stress and load check and testing.

> [how to create simulator for web application for load test and stress test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627084/how-to-create-simulator-for-web-application-for-load-test-and-stress-test)

There´re plenty of frameworks to test Server side load, but it´s important to point what framework / lenguage are you using to get more accurate responses.

UPDATE

JMeter also works for PHP based web services. Taken from it´s documentation

What can I do with it?

> Apache JMeter may be used to test performance both on static and
>   dynamic resources (Files, Web dynamic languages - **PHP**, Java, ASP.NET,
>   etc. -, Java Objects, Data Bases and Queries, FTP Servers and more).
>   It can be used to simulate a heavy load on a server, group of servers,
>   network or object to test its strength or to analyze overall
>   performance under different load types. You can use it to make a
>   graphical analysis of performance or to test your server/script/object
>   behavior under heavy concurrent load.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: My web server on WAMP server(using PHP). is there any tool for WAMPSERVER

Comment: @AtulK updated my answer, basically JMeter works for PHP too. That should work for you.